# How to bind a print button to a form to print out rdlc report?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Here is my code, the error I get is "frmPrint" does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments.

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (frmPrint frm = new frmPrint(receiptBindingSource.DataSource as List<Receipt>, string.Format("{0}€", total))) ;
            
        }
```

Comment: Then add one? in `frmPrint` you should have `publie frmPrint(List<Receipt> lst, string format) { ... }`.

Comment: ... and sorry for the typo. `public`.